# Python : AttributeError: 'ApiClient' object has no attribute 'configure_jwt_authorization_flow'

Tags: python, docusignapi

I am getting an attribute error while running the code given below:

```py
import base64
import subprocess
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function
from pprint import pprint
import unittest
import webbrowser
import docusign_esign as docusign
from docusign_esign import AuthenticationApi, TemplatesApi,EnvelopesApi,ApiClient
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from os import path
import requests

integrator_key = "XYZ"
base_url = "https://www.docusign.net/restapi"
oauth_base_url = "account.docusign.com" #use account-d.docusign.com for sandbox    
redirect_uri = "https://www.docusign.com/api"    
user_id = 'MNO'     
private_key_filename = "docusign_private_key.txt"    
client_secret = 'ABC' #production    
account_id = 'QRS'

api_client = docusign.ApiClient(base_url)    
api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow(integrator_key, client_secret, redirect_uri)
```

ERROR:

```
AttributeError                            
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1abfece08e05> in <module>()
     55 api_client = docusign.ApiClient(base_url)
     56 # make sure to pass the redirect uri
---> 57 api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow(integrator_key, client_secret, redirect_uri)

AttributeError: 'ApiClient' object has no attribute 'configure_jwt_authorization_flow'
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that, Python Docusign SDK interface has changed in the latest versions but the Official code examples still uses the old version.

So for obtaining JWT bearer tokens, instead of `configure_jwt_authorization_flow` you need to use `request_jwt_user_token` function of ApiClient object.

Code Sample:

```
def update_token(api_client):
    key_data = None
    with open(<rsa private key file>, mode='rb') as file:
        key_data = file.read()

    if key_data is None:
        return None

    jwt_token = api_client.request_jwt_user_token( <INTEGRATION_KEY>,
                                                   <USER_ID>,
                                                   <AUTH_HOST>,
                                                   key_data,
                                                   <token expiration interval> )
    if jwt_token is not None:
        print(jwt_token.access_token)
```

Answer (score 0):

have you configured your Integration Key in DocuSign? did you get a private RSA key? this is required to use JWT

Also note that your redirect_uri doesn't seem correct. That uri should point to your code, not to Docusign.

Comment: Thanks Inbar.. Looks like a version issue. I uninstalled a later version and installed V1.0.3 of docusign-esign

Comment: glad you got it working, can you please mark question as answered?